# How do i paste an image onto every frame in a gif in ruby with rmagick

Tags: ruby, image, imagemagick, gif

```
require 'rmagick'
require 'open-uri'
include Magick

giflist = Magick::ImageList.new('pewpewpew.gif')
open('avatar.jpg', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/120571255635181568/8e37daf54a9c631afe659ebcb87af959.jpg').read
end

avatar = Magick::Image.read('avatar.jpg').first

newavatar = Draw.new {
  self.fill = 'black'
  self.stroke = 'transparent'
  self.tile = avatar
  self.fill_pattern = avatar
  self.stroke_pattern = avatar
  self.gravity = NorthGravity
}
giflist.each { |image| newavatar.composite(20, 20, 40, 40, image) }# x, y, width, height, image
giflist.write('newgif.gif')
```

So basically i'm trying to paste this jpg onto a gif, but for some reason nothings happening and i'm not getting any errors. the image is downloaded properly so i know thats not an issue

gif -> [Gif Link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/225375815087554563/255817574137200640/pewpewpew.gif)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read Ruby, but I am guessing your `newavatar` may not contain anything because you may not have specified aa size when drawing it - try writing it out on its own maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to be completely honest, I have no idea why this isn't erroring as written. I can tell you Ruby'isms on why things aren't working, but the more I try and explain the behavior, the more I fail to prove it.

Anyway, here's what I think I know:

```
newavatar.composite(20, 20, 40, 40, image)
```

This is drawing the gif *on top of* the avatar. But you can't just swap the variables. That blows up with "no `cur_image` defined".

```
giflist.each { |image| newavatar.composite(20, 20, 40, 40, image) }
```

Either each of the frames are being returned into `newavatar`, or they're just being thrown away since there's no assignment happening (`image = giflist.each { … }`). But again, no matter which way I try and put it together, I get a variety of errors.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
require 'rmagick'
require 'open-uri'
include Magick

giflist = Magick::ImageList.new('pewpewpew.gif')
open('avatar.jpg', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/120571255635181568/8e37daf54a9c631afe659ebcb87af959.jpg').read
end

avatar = Magick::Image.read('avatar.jpg').first

giflist.each { |image| image.composite!(avatar, NorthWestGravity, 40, 40, OverCompositeOp) }
giflist.write('newgif.gif')
```

And more importantly, the result:

[image: Avatar overlaid on gif]

You'll note the use of `composite!`, which replaces the frames in place (still in the `giflist` variable).

The last part you have to do is reduce the size of the avatar to 40x40, which should only be a single line, and I'm pretty sure that's all that's left.

Much simpler, no?

Comment: Worked very well, thanks for the help :) i was just stuck because i ran into that "no `cur_image` error and was unsure at what to do. I think i infact tried `composite!` but i may have had issues due to not assigning the gravity :s